# mongodb if field has given value in one collection then search corresponding field in another collections and return combined values from many collec

Tags: mongodb

let's say I have 3 collections in MongoDB

```
  "Col1": [
    {
      "accountCode": "xyz",
      "ITSM": "SNOW",
      "anotherFieldxxx": "x"
    },
    {
      "accountCode": "abc",
      "ITSM": "SNOW",
      "anotherFieldxxx": "x"
    }
  ],
  "Col2": [
    {
      "accountCode": "xyz",
      "manager": "John",
      "anotherFieldyyy": "yyy"
    },
    {
      "accountCode": "abc",
      "manager": "Lisa",
      "anotherFieldyyy": "yyy"
    }
  ],
  "Col3": [
    {
      "accountCode": "xyz",
      "admin": "Peter",
      "anotherFieldzzz": "z"
    },
    {
      "accountCode": "abc",
      "admin": "Mona",
      "anotherFieldyyy": "yyy"
    }
  ]
```

In the query I want to give only one value and it's `"ITSM" : "SNOW"`
If there is many documents in `Col1` with `"ITSM" : "SNOW"` then I want to search for `"accountCode"` in `Col2` and get `"manager"` value, then search for the same `"accountCode"` in `Col3` and get `"admin"` value. Finally I want to get output like:

```
{"accountCode" : "xyz",
"ITSM" : "SNOW",
"manager" : "John",
"admin" : "Peter"},
{"accountCode" : "abc",
"ITSM" : "SNOW",
"manager" : "Paul",
"admin" : "Stephen"}
```

I tried with Aggregation but I am just beginner in MongoDb and finally I gave up.
Can you suggest what I should use to get my result?

---update

I have such query

```
db.Col1.aggregate([
    {$project: {"anotherFieldxxx": 0}},
    {$match: {"accountCode": "xyz"}},   
    {$lookup:   {   
                    from: "Col2",
                    localField: "accountCode",
                    foreignField: "accountCode",
                    as: "Col2"
     }},
      {     $unwind:    "$Col2" },
      {     $project: { "Col2.anotherFieldyyy" : 0  }},
      {     $match:     { "accountCode" : "xyz"}},
  {
    $lookup: {
                    from: "Col3",
                    localField: "accountCode",
                    foreignField: "accountCode",
                    as: "Col3"
    }},
  {$unwind: "$Col3"},
  {$project: {"Col2.anotherFieldzzz": 0}}
])Pretty()
```

but what if there are also documents with `"accountCode" : "abc"` in all collections?

Comment: Try using `$lookup` (twice)

Comment: @nimrodserok I tried `$lookup` but: 
I can't get only fields which I want from `Col1` - it gives me always all fields. By `$project` I can limit only fields from `Col2` and `Col3`

Comment: @nimrodserok and let's say in `Col1` there is 30 documents with `"ITSM" : "SNOW"` value. How can I pass these `accountCode`s from `Col1` to be searched in `Col2` and `Col3` ?

Comment: Use an aggregation pipeline that start with a `$match` step. Then you will only work will relevant documents. Also, you can use `$lookup` with pipeline to project only the fields that you need

Comment: @nimrodserok I updated post with new query with things you suggested, but it works only for `xyz` value which I pass in the query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option is to `$match` documents with your wanted value and then use there `accountCode` for `$lookup`. No need to limit the search to one specific `accountCode`:

```
db.Col1.aggregate([
  {$match: {"ITSM": "SNOW"}},
  {$lookup: {
      from: "Col2",
      localField: "accountCode",
      foreignField: "accountCode",
      pipeline: [{$project: {manager: 1, _id: 0}}],
      as: "Res2"
  }},
  {$lookup: {
      from: "Col3",
      localField: "accountCode",
      foreignField: "accountCode",
      pipeline: [{$project: {admin: 1, _id: 0}}],
      as: "Res3"
  }},
  {$project: {
      _id: 0,
      accountCode: 1,
      ITSM: 1,
      manager: {$first: "$Res2.manager"},
      admin: {$first: "$Res3.admin"}
  }}
])
```

See how it works on the [playground example](https://mongoplayground.net/p/iCBOH4hVkI_)

Answer (score 0):

```
db.Col1.aggregate([
  {
    $project: { "anotherFieldxxx": 0 }
  },
  {
    $match: { "accountCode": "xyz" }
  },
  {
    $lookup: {
      from: "Col2",
      localField: "accountCode",
      foreignField: "accountCode",
      as: "Res2"
    }
  },
  {
    $lookup: {
      from: "Col3",
      localField: "accountCode",
      foreignField: "accountCode",
      as: "Res3"
    }
  },
  { $unwind: "$Res2" },
  { $unwind: "$Res3" },
  {
    $project: {
      accountCode: 1,
      ITSM: 1,
      manager: "$Res2.manager",
      admin: "$Res3.admin"
    }
  }
])
```

[Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/lRA6HFPUjlS)